# Logstash Date Parsing different

Tags: logstash

I'm trying to create a filter to parse the date from my log files. The filter is set up like this:

```
filter {
    date {
            match => [ "timestamp", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS" ]
    }
}
```

The relevant log messages are structured like this:

```
[2018-09-18 10:13:17,623] [main] INFO  com.test.pack - Message
[2018-09-18 10:13:17,634] [main] INFO  com.test.pack - Message
[2018-09-18 10:13:17,641] [main] INFO  com.test.pack - Message
```

The output from Logstash is:

```
{
      "host" => "hostname",
"@timestamp" => 2018-09-19T15:19:50.561Z,
   "message" => "[2018-09-18 10:13:17,623] [main] INFO com.test.pack - Message",
      "path" => "/path/to/file.log",
  "@version" => "1"
}
{
      "host" => "hostname",
"@timestamp" => 2018-09-19T15:19:50.561Z,
   "message" => "[2018-09-18 10:13:17,634] [main] INFO com.test.pack - Message",
      "path" => "/path/to/file.log",
  "@version" => "1"
}
{
      "host" => "hostname",
"@timestamp" => 2018-09-19T15:19:50.561Z,
   "message" => "[2018-09-18 10:13:17,641] [main] INFO com.test.pack - Message",
      "path" => "/path/to/file.log",
  "@version" => "1"
}
```

So the logstash timestamp varies in both the date as well as the time. The log messages which are dated on the **17th** also show up as the **19th**. Any ideas what I'm missing in my filtering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will also need a grok filter i to extract timestamp from message. Please try something like this.

```
filter {
    grok {
            match => {"message" => "[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}] [main] %{GREEDYDATA:restOfMessage}"}
  }
    date {
            match => [ "timestamp", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS" ]
             timezone => "Etc/UCT"
    }
}
```

Please choose timezone appropriately as available here https://www.joda.org/joda-time/timezones.html. It may possibly be EST5EDT, EST, UTC or something else.

Comment: This fixes the date issue but I'm seeing a 4 hour difference between the grok extracted timestamp and the filtered timestamp from date.

    "@timestamp" => 2018-09-18T14:13:17.775Z, -------- 
     "timestamp" => "2018-09-18 10:13:17,775"

Comment: Which timezone your server in?

Comment: Eastern Standard Time

Comment: Updated answer with timezone. Please try. Timezone may be EST or EST5EDT or something else.

Comment: Fixed by using Etc/UCT